# Cordova Android Build Exit Code 8

Tags: java, android, cordova, ant, ionic-framework

I've been working on a Cordova project for iOS for the last couple of months, and now I want to move over and test the Android portion. I've tried twice of installing the Android SDK, JDK, Ant, and putting them in the Path Environment Variable but I just can't get the app to build. I tried looking around at other questions but couldn't seem to find a definitive answer.

So, when I go to build the Android platform, this is the error that I get:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The following
error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Compile failed;
see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 3 seconds

C:\Users\thomas\Desktop\batapp\BatNetting\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q
\q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant/debug/-f/C:\Users\thomas\Desktop\
batapp\BatNetting\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absoule.dir=
ant-gen
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: C:\Users\thomas\Desktop\batapp\
BatNetting\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

I'm really not sure what could be causing this. Like I said, I've tried reinstalling the SDK, Java, Ant and double checked the Path. First, I tried pulling the files from a local Git server, then I removed them and copied them straight from the project I had open on the Mac VM I had been working on. I have also tried using both `cordova build android` and `ionic build android`, but both have the same result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

***Update***

I've tried creating a new app with ionic and everything in the new app works fine. I've successfully created a project, added Android as a platform, built and ran the Android project. So, it seems to be something with the app that already exists that doesn't seem to be agreeing with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out. I was just having a problem with one of my plugins. It required a java library that wasn't in my project. Once I put the library in the project, it was able to build and run fine.

Comment: and what was that this answere, this absolute no value to the community

Comment: I was using a library call html2pdf and it required iText.jar, but I didn't know that. So, once I added iText.jar to the plugin, it built fine.

Comment: @BogdanM. Actually this answer is valuable because I am facing the same situation so it's good to know what the problem was.

Comment: As i said, it requires  more info like what plugin or what library was missing or what caused actually the problem. Just by tell ing us this much i found the answer lousy. 
@Atarienerd80 thanks for the  additional comment.